# Why can't DynaLoader.pm load SSleay.dll for Net::SSLeay and Crypt::SSLeay?

Tags: perl

I have Perl v5.10. I am trying to install Net::SSLeay 1.30 and Crypt::SSLeay 0.57.
I have already installed OpenSSL 0.9.8e.

For Net::SSLeay 1.30 I followed these steps:

```
perl Makefile.PL -windows C:\openssl
nmake
nmake test  -- test fails
nmake install

perl test.pl
```

but I got an fatal error as:

```
D:\perl\Net_SSLeay.pm-1.30>perl -w test.pl
1..20
Can't load 'D:/perl/site/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.dll' for module Net::SSLeay: load_file:The specified module could not be found at D:/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 203.
 at test.pl line 25
Compilation failed in require at test.pl line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 25.
```

I got the same results for Crypt::SSLeay 0.57.

Comment: There's no need for multiple question marks.

Comment: Can you should us the output of `make test` and `make install`?

Answer (score 6):

Randy Kobes has [an answer for this on the Perl Win32 mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/perl-win32-users@listserv.activestate.com/msg32520.html). Does your PATH environment variable contain the directory that contains libeay32.dll or ssleay32.dll?

There are many other answers that you can find in Google too. In cases like these, I take the whole error message and shove it into the Google search bar. I start cutting out parts of the error message, such as the specific paths, until I get [some search results](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=safari&rls=en-us&q=module+Net%3A%3ASSLeay%3A+load_file%3AThe+specified+module+could+not+be+found&btnG=Search). This almost always works for me since I'm rarely the first person to have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Shared libs often have external dependencies, and on some operating systems those dependencies need to be immediately fulfilled when the first shared library is loaded, like your `SSLeay.dll`, which usually needs the two crypto libs. On linux you can check with `ldd` the run-time behavior, if all libs are found.

To debug this add the env var PERL_DL_DEBUG=5, like `set PERL_DL_DEBUG=5` and try again or use the external tool `depends.exe` to see what dll's exactly are missing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Windows Par::Packer. The resulting myprogram.exe had trouble loading rurban's hint with PERL_DL_DEBUG

```
Can't load 'temp\7e717f68.xs.dll' for module Crypt::SSLeay: load_file:Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden at <embedded>/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
  at <embedded>/PAR/Heavy.pm line 95.
```

I was not able to find out which dlls to include with pp. After these hints I was simply looking to the dll-file with a hex editor and found this string: libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll - this was the dll to include into my "compiled" exe-program:

```
pp -M Crypt::SSLeay ^
   -l c:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/Crypt/SSLeay/SSLeay.xs.dll ^
   -l c:/strawberry/c/bin/libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem with a fresh install of Strawberry Perl 5.30.  Googling the error just gives a bunch of unanswered, or half answered questions.  Rurban is pointing in the right direction with using **depends.exe**.  Opening **ssleay.xs.dll** and waiting for it to finishing throwing errors shows 5 main dll's that it depends on.  2 of which are windows core dll's, and 3 from openssl and perl.  In the strawberry install, the 2 dll's related to crypto are in the `[perlinstallpath]\c\bin` folder.  Add this to your windows **`%PATH%`** variable and it will start working.

Comment: if you're answering the question try putting your content into paragraph and use appropriate markers for highlighting to increase readability.